# Highcharts multiple series from json

Tags: ajax, json, highcharts, series

My JSON looks like:
[[[773,1363709520],[774,1363709580]],[[1546,1363709520],[1548,1363709580]]]

I would like highcharts to create a new series every time it reaches a new JSON array: [[1546,1363709520],[1548,1363709580]]

I have a hard coded version, but making my data[[]] is not helping...

```
$(function () {

var data = [];
var data1 = [];
$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:8080/vdm-stats-core/stats/metrics?from=2&src=org.example.fib&customer=customer0&server=server0&metric=responses.count",
    dataType: "jsonp", // Notice! JSONP <-- P (lowercase)
    jsonp: "callback",
    success: function (inData) {
        console.log(inData[0][1][0]);
        var xval = new Date();
        for (a = 0; a < inData.length; a++) {
            for (i = 0; i < inData[a].length; i++) {
                var yval = inData[a][i][0];
                xval = inData[a][i][1];
                var x = [xval, yval];
                if (a == 0) {
                    data.push(x);
                }
                if (a > 0) {
                    data1.push(x);
                }
            }
        }
        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Test',
            },

            rangeSelector: {
                selected: 1
            },

            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime'
            },

            series: [{
                name: 'Customer0',
                data: data
            }, {
                name: 'Customer1',
                data: data1
            }]
        });
    },
    error: function () {
        console.log(arguments);
    }
});
```

});

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to understand your code, here's my intepretation;

```
function success(inData) {

   var customerNr,
       timestamp,
       VALUE = 0,
       TIMESTAMP = 1,
       series = {},
       len = inData.length,
       yval,
       item;

        for (customerNr = 0; customerNr < len; customerNr++) {
            // Init series object literal for customer
            series[customerNr] = {
                name : 'Customer '+customerNr.toString(),
                data : []
            };
            // Setup data for customer
            for (item = 0; item < inData[customerNr].length; item++) {
                yval = inData[customerNr][item][VALUE];
                timestamp = inData[customerNr][item][TIMESTAMP];
                series[customerNr].data.push([timestamp,yval]);
            }
            // Add series, but redraw only on last customer
            chart.addSeries(series[customerNr],customerNr===len-1);

        }
```

};

You recycle the series object for each customer, but I've added a customerNr property. addSeries method in Highchart will by default redraw chart (http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.addSeries()). I've selected to only redraw chart on last customer. Forked fiddle example at; http://jsfiddle.net/hkskoglund/VVLNV/

Comment: Thank you so much :) If I had enough reputation, I would have upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

The important thing to keep in mind is that the series object is already a json object...
So the easiest thing to do, assuming you control the creation of the json file, is format the json output as the entire series object:

```
[{ name: 'Customer0', data: [[773,1363709520],[774,1363709580]] }, { name: 'Customer1', data: [[1546,1363709520],[1548,1363709580]] }]
```

and then:

```
series: myData
```

Comment: That is just the JSON format. The JSON creation is not controlled. There might be 4 arrays in the json in which 4 series would be needed.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work:
Had to reset my series data.

```
$(function () {
        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Test',
            },

            rangeSelector: {
                selected: 1
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime'
            },

            series: []
        });

$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:8080/vdm-stats-core/stats/metrics?from=200&src=org.example.fib&customer=customer0&server=server0&metric=responses.count",
    dataType: "jsonp", // Notice! JSONP <-- P (lowercase)
    jsonp: "callback",
    success: function (inData) {
        var xval = new Date();
        var series = {
            name: 'Customer',
            data: []
        }
        for (a = 0; a < inData.length; a++) {
            for (i = 0; i < inData[a].length; i++) {
                var yval = inData[a][i][0];
                xval = inData[a][i][1];
                var x = [xval, yval];
                 series.data.push(x);
            }
            chart.addSeries(series);
            series.data = [];
        }
    },
    error: function () {
        console.log(arguments);
    }
});
```

});